# LinearLayout View arrangement

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I need to arrange 4 `FloatingActionButton`s evenly, horizontally.

After reading many answers on SO, it turns out that the best way to do it is to have them in a `LinearLayout` with a `layout_width` of `0dp` and all the buttons with a `layout_weight` of `1`. After many attempts, `layout_width` of `0dp` never worked.

Here's what I did:

```
     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
              :
              : > 
        <RelativeLayout
                :
                : >
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbarBack"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/rlDetailLayoutBack"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fabDirections"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/directions1"
                    android:borderWidth="0dp"
                    android:elevation="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fabCallMobile"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/mobile"
                    android:borderWidth="0dp"
                    android:elevation="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fabCallLandline"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/landline"
                    android:borderWidth="0dp"
                    android:elevation="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/fabWebsite"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/website1"
                    android:borderWidth="0dp"
                    android:elevation="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

            </LinearLayout>
                 :
                 :
         </RelativeLayout>
     </android.support.v7.widgetCardView>
```

The rendering in Android Studio (v1.5.1) with **API 21 (Android 5.0.1)** is like this:

[image]

...and with **API 17 (Android 4.2.2)**, it is like this (the images in the FAB appear correctly on a physical device, so that's not a problem):

[image]

My questions are:

- Why are the buttons not uniformly laid out in API 21?
- How can even even distribution (in fact, *overall consistency*) be achieved irrespective of the API?
- How to get rid of the ugly lines bordering the buttons in API 21?

Many thanks in advance!

Courtesy the answer below from Nolly J, this is how the layout looks ***now*** on API 21, and works as well on API 17.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-"How can even distribution be achieved irrespective of the API".

I have recreated your LinearLayout in a way that four horizontal columns are place beside which other using layout_weight

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbarBack"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rlDetailLayoutBack"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabDirections"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/direction1"
            android:borderWidth="0dp"
            android:elevation="8dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabCallMobile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/mobile"
            android:borderWidth="0dp"
            android:elevation="0dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabCallLandline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/landline"
            android:borderWidth="0dp"
            android:elevation="0dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabWebsite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/website1"
            android:borderWidth="0dp"
            android:elevation="0dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

For other questions, refer to @Charles Durham solution

Comment: thank you. Copy-pasted your recreation and it works on both APIs. However, the ugly border lines are still there on API 21. Any further advice?

Comment: Try android:background="@android:color/transparent" and let me know if it works

Comment: Just did that inside the FAB element. The border lines remain, the button itself disappears.

Answer (score 1):

What's going on is you're seeing how the elevation is applied to the FAB on pre-lollipop.

In short, all FABs on API levels before v21 have 16dp padding where as FABS on v21+ have 0dp padding. This is inbuilt to support elevation pre-lollipop.

You should be able to add 16dp padding left/right in your styles-v21 and apply that as the padding to your FABs.

Comment: thanks for the insight. Wish I could have accepted more than one answer. Went for the other one because it was just _copy-paste and **voila**!_ Cheers!